# Remove messy leading whitespace in Vim on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, vim

I am copying code from website [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) and pasting into the Vim editor in a terminal on Mac OS X:

[pylab_examples example code: ellipse_demo.py](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/)

While this works fine in [BBEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBEdit):

```
`from pylab import figure, show, rand
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

NUM = 250

ells = [Ellipse(xy=rand(2)*10, width=rand(), height=rand(), angle=rand()*360)
        for i in xrange(NUM)]

fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
for e in ells:
    ax.add_artist(e)
    e.set_clip_box(ax.bbox)
    e.set_alpha(rand())
    e.set_facecolor(rand(3))

ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)

show()
```

That is, all the code is properly aligned. In Vim it looks like this:

```
from pylab import figure, show, rand
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

NUM = 250

ells = [Ellipse(xy=rand(2)*10, width=rand(), height=rand(), angle=rand()*360)
        for i in xrange(NUM)]

            fig = figure()
            ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
            for e in ells:
                    ax.add_artist(e)
                        e.set_clip_box(ax.bbox)
                            e.set_alpha(rand())
                                e.set_facecolor(rand(3))

                                ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
                                ax.set_ylim(0, 10)

                                show()
```

How to fix this annoying situation? Does it have something to do with the different carriage return / line feed conventions on the Mac?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [`:set paste`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'paste') command before pasting the text. This turns off autoindent plus various other things that can interfere with pasting. To restore normal operation, use `:set nopaste`.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what to suggest then. What you describe is precisely the problem that the `:set paste` command is designed to solve. I use it whenever I am faced with the same problem and it works for me.

Comment: off that previous comment of mine. Clearly too late at night here in London! Got it working. Thanks Greg nice one.

Answer (score 2):

Or use `:r!pbpaste` -- that inserts output from the `pbpaste` command (which happens to be the current paste buffer) under the current line; no need to mess about with modes and such.

Comment: Using an external command is overkill as there is :put and "+p that do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Not in OS X; see my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to, you could just use `cat(1)`:

```
$ cat > newfile.py
Paste the code here, then press Ctrl-D for EOF.
Make sure to type EOF on an otherwise empty line
or bad things will happen to your children.
$ vi newfile.py
```

Should work.

Comment: I recommend the :set paste version, especially now that I know about it, but at the time I started posting I didn't know it worked for you, so I posted it just in case.

Comment: I always used this method in the past, but after learning about "set paste" I'll likely switch too.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the `:set paste` command already mentioned, you can always do `"+p` to paste the contents of the clipboard into the current location.  I've not used Vim on Mac OS X, but I'm sure this is still valid.  On Linux, there's `"*p` for the selection clipboard and `"+p` for the copy-and-paste clipboard; on Windows, they both point to the system clipboard.  `"+p` is a bit of an odd command at first, but once you're used to using this type of command, it becomes very quick.  Alternatively you could use `:put +` to do the same thing.

```
:help quote
:help put
:help :put
:help registers
```

Comment: On OS X this doesn't seem to work; when I tested it, the `+` register didn't pull from the system clipboard, just from vi's internal register.  I tried both `vi` and `vim`, running in both xterm and Apple's native Terminal.app; `:r!pbpaste` works, vi's register integration doesn't.

Comment: This is the case for macVim, but I think it's not the + register in the command line vim

Answer (score -1):

If you were using emacs, it would be a simple matter of `M-x mark-whole-buffer` and `M-x indent-region`.

Comment: Contrary to popular believe, "Use something else" is rarely the solution.

Comment: Thanks jrockway haha. Sadly the indents get incrementally larger on each line so doesn't help, or I would have used Vim's < command ;)

Comment: And, as we see, since he's using Vim, it's as easy as `:set paste`.

Comment: I missed the part about pasting.  In that case, it Just Works.

Comment: (In the case of pasting the second example into emacs, only the last three lines are left with incorrect indentation.)

Comment: Vim also has an auto-indent function (gg=G for example), but this is not necessarily helpful for python code as it is impossible for emacs or Vim to know the indent level for a line of python code (unless it's the line immediately after a line ending ':').